# Node.js - Use variable as object name to call method

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, object, argv

I am new to node and just trying to use the process.argv to call a method on the correct object, but I keep getting an error it cant read property of undefined.

```
// returns with undefined error
var stops_input = process.argv[3];
this[process.argv[3]].displayStops();

// hard-coding object name works with the method:
N.displayStops();

// displayStops method
this.displayStops = function(){
  string = "";

  stops.forEach(function(i){
    if (i === stops[stops.length -1]) {
      string += i;
    } else {
      string += i + ", ";
    }
  });

  console.log(this.name + " train stops: " + string);
}
```

Thanks for taking a look. Any ideas as to how to call the object using a variable from the node terminal console?

Comment: Did you try `this[process.argv[3]]()`

Comment: this[process.argv[3]]().displayStops(); throws me this error:
TypeError: this[process.argv[3]] is not a function

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on here. Is `N` an object with a method `displayStops()`? And is `N` a property of whatever object `this` refers to, in this context? And is `N` the second argument you pass when you run your program from the command line (`process.argv[3]` should be the second argument)? Or is `N` a free-floating variable (in which case, you can't do what you are trying to do, but there are workarounds)?

Comment: Right so N is an object that has the method `displayStops()`, and N was the value of the `process.argv[3]` from the terminal. I was using `this` after trying to find some help online, but I think what I'm trying to do isn't actually possible after some research. That is, passing the name of the object as a variable from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

try using `global` instead of `this`...

```
global[process.argv[3]].displayStops();
```

This assumes that `N` is the 2nd argument passed to the node script, and that it exists in the global scope, and has a method `displayStops` attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following.

```
// Your argument from the commandline (faked for your pleasure)
var method = 'xxx'

// 1. Create a function as normal
function xxx() {
    return 'xxx'
}

// 1. Create a reference to it
var callable = {xxx: xxx}

// 1. Call it
callable[method]()
```

To see what's in your context:

```
console.log(this); // {}
console.log(global.xxx); // undefined
console.log(Object.keys(global)); // Run to see the list
```

If you want to stick with `this`, change this:

```
this[process.argv[3]]().displayStops()
```

To this:

```
this[process.argv[3]]()
```

The former equates to:

```
this['displayStops']().displayStops()
```

But you want the later, which equates to:

```
this['displayStops']() // The same as calling this.displayStops()
```

Comment: `callable[method]()`

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to node and just trying to use the process.argv to call a
>   method on the correct object, but I keep getting an error it cant read
>   property of undefined.

process.argv will return an array of parameters

so of you call

```
node program.js 1 2 3
```

in the terminal

```
var params = process.argv;
console.log(params);
```

You will get

```
[node, path/to/program.js, someMethod, 2, 3]
```

Assuming the first argument you passed is an object

```
var firstParam = process.argv[2];
```

Now if you have an object defined with a method...

```
var obj = {
    someMethod : function() {
        console.log("Hello");             
    }
}
```

You can call this method like so

```
obj["someMethod"]();
obj[firstParam]();
obj.someMethod();
```

They should all produce "hello"